# Mocking certificate using WebMock Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webmock

I have a webscraper in ruby that analyses certificates by using this:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(http_endpoint.host, http_endpoint.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
http.start do |h|
    @cert = h.peer_cert
end
```

Is it possible to mock this request using webmock and give a fake certificate during testing?

Answer (score -1):

I see that this is an old question but [this](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/50#issuecomment-482894294) might help